# Term for Subversive, Passive-Aggressive Insults (In which the insulter has plausible deniability, concerning any actual effort at offense)

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology

To clarify, what I'm seeking is a term that represents a speaker offering a backhanded compliment, in which the speaker is the only one that doesn't share this point of view.

Example: "Personally, I think you were hilarious -- even if you did ruin the entire event, cheated the children, and the rest of the world hates your guts ..."

I'd also be interested in different takes on the purposeful, yet shielded (cheeky) offense and a completely unintentional, clueless (friendly) offense.

Comment: I'd call this a snide remark.

Comment: A sarcastic remark would be a good way to call it especially if the act is intentional

Comment: You used the term *backhanded compliment* in describing your question. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Apparently they're also called ["Stealth Insults"](https://allthetropes.orain.org/wiki/Stealth_Insult).    My favorite has got to be Churchill's:  *'It is said that I have called the honorable member a liar. It is true and I am sorry.'*

Comment: I think it's called the *Mark Antony Effect*.

Comment: As @ghoppe says, [backhanded complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insult#Backhanded_compliment) means: A backhanded compliment, also known as a left-handed compliment or asteism, is an insult that is disguised as a compliment. Sometimes, a backhanded compliment may be inadvertent. However, the term usually connotes an intent to belittle or condescend.[5]

Comment: This is irony, or an ironic compliment. You express the opposite of the literal meaning of your words. It's more subtle and deniable than sarcasm.

Comment: *snide remark* should be the answer here, courtesy of @Bookeater. snide: "derogatory or mocking in an indirect way."

Comment: @Jason M 's suggestion of an "ironic compliment" feels right. At the least, it's the response that feels most related to the intention of my question, with the emphasis on plausible deniability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the term you are looking for is called negging, although it is rather colloquial:

> Negging is a rhetorical strategy whereby a person makes a deliberate
>   backhanded compliment or otherwise insulting remark to another person
>   in order to undermine his or her confidence in a way that gains
>   approval.

Comment: I'd say this is about as close as we can get to the "purposeful, yet shielded (cheeky) offense." It is rather colloquial but, it's possible we'll find unique, colloquial answers to this, everywhere (if any concept exists for it.) I do still like "ironic compliment" for the more unintentional occurrences.

Answer (score -2):

Insinuate (?)
It doesn't fit in your sentence, but is maybe a start...

Comment: Insinuate refers to the act of suggesting something. It does not qualify to what the OP requires.

Comment: Hi HimThere, welcome to EL&U!  Your answer, in its current state is more like a comment (which you may not have sufficient permissions, yet, to post).  An answer should directly answer the question and include cited resources. Please take the site tour to learn the best ways to participate here! http://english.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Yeah - okay.  I didn't even know this site existed this morning!  Guess I've got some learning to do.  Thanks Kristina!